# Offset Header Highlight with ::before and z-index -- CSS only

Tags: css, pseudo-element

This is my first question on Stack, so if I break conventions, please correct/inform so I can query this resource better next time!

I am trying to style a header element with an offset highlight that covers the bottom half of the header text, like this:

[see the blue highlight on the "bottleneck" -- http://jessecha.se/work/blueapron.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m4W8.png)

The author achieves it with a ::before element and z-index of -1. Whether I use ::before or ::after, I am having trouble:

1) getting the pseudo-element to align to the bottom of the header element

2) getting the pseudo-element to be the same width as the header without specifying pixel width. Would the header be better of set to display as table?

Here's the code:

```css
h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  background: orange;
  left: 0;
  height: .6em;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h2 style="width: 500px">
      Highlighting Header Styles
    </h2>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Add `position: relative` to `h2` and on `h2:after` use  `bottom: 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `h2` element need to be `position: relative` (the position:absolute elements need 
a container element to be position:relative or absolute) and the `h2` element need to 
be `display: inline-block` (because of the width) and the `:after` element add `width: 100%`

```css
h2{
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: orange;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: .6em;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>
  <article>
    <h2>
      Highlighting Header Styles
    </h2>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```